# Negative multidimensional arrays index js

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I am trying set the position map[-1][-1].
But don´t make sense.

```
var map = [];
map[-1] = 'less one';
map[-1][-1] = 'less one to quad';
console.log(map[-1]); //less one
console.log(map[-1][-1]); //undefined
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to set `map[-1]` as an array before you can set an attribute to it:

```js
var map = [];
map[-1] = ['less one'];
map[-1][-1] = 'less one to quad';
console.log(map[-1]); //less one
console.log(map[-1][-1]);
```

You might want to do this if you want a multi dimensional array:

```js
var map = []
map.push(['less one'])
map[map.length-1].push('less one to quad')

console.log(map)
console.log(map.slice(-1)[0])
console.log(map.slice(-1)[0].slice(-1)[0])
```